# How to get the real screensize in java?

Tags: java, awt

I used to use

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.getscreensize()
```

But it can't work after I update java from JDK8u201 to JDK8u211. The real screensize of my computer is `2736*1824`, but the result it return is `1368*912`.

I've confirmed it relates to the screen scale and layout which is 200%, but I just want to get the real screensize despite the scale. How can I get it now ? I've looked up the release notes for updates but couldn't find it. My OS version is Windows 10 17134.706

Comment: Does this work?: GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds()

Comment: What do you mean by "Zoom"?

Comment: It got the same result. I’m not a native English speaker, maybe it should called “Scale and layout” I’ve confirmed that it’s the point because it returns the correct result when I set the scale and layout 100%.

Comment: I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why do you need the screen size?  If it’s for centering a window, you can do that with [setLocationRelativeTo(null)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29).  For a full screen window, you should maximize it or use GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow.